# Inherit from two classes (either or)

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have the following issue with class inheritance. Given class `A`, `B`, `C` as follows

```
class A(object):
    ...

class B(A):
    ...

class C(A):
    ...
```

I want a class `D` that can either inherit from `B` or from `C`, depending on the use case.
Right now, I have solved this issue by having a dynamic class definition:

```
def D(base_class, parameter1, parameter2):
    class D(base_class):
        ...
    return D(parameter1, parameter2)
```

Is this the proper way to do it, or is there a better way of solving this issue?

Comment: Just don't use inheritance at all. Use composition. Note, this creates a unique class *for every instance you create*. Which is wasteful, and will lead to weird semantics.

Comment: With `d1 = D(A, x, y)` and `d2 = D(A, x, y)`, `d1` and `d2` will *not* have the same type. It doesn't matter that you used `D` as the name for the two types, they are still distinct.

Comment: What is the real world use case for wanting to do this? If you have two types and you want a third "type" that can behave like either of the first two, what is the advantage of that?

Comment: If you have one class inherit from `B` and another from `C`, those are *two different classes*, no matter how similar their interfaces may be.

Comment: I would check if this D class have been created already (by caching them in a `dict`) Just to make sure you don't re-create the same class over and over. But either way, I'm not sure what's the use case you are trying to solve

Comment: @orlevii that sounds like a really over-engineered way of just creating two classes that inherit from different parents.

Comment: @chepner thanks for that comment... It's bad that `d1` and `d2` have different types... My real life use case is a loan `A` that can either have a regular payment schedule `B` or an irregular one `C`. The `D` is a loan that has a different payment structure wrt `A` but can be regular or irregular.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have `D` both create a class *and* return an instance, have it just return the class, which you can then use to create multiple instances as necessary.

```
def make_D(base_class):
    class D(base_class):
        ...
    return D

DB = make_D(B)
DC = make_D(C)

d1 = DB(...)
d2 = DC(...)
d3 = DC(...)
```

At this point, you should consider whether you actually *need* a factory function to define your subclasses, rather than simply define `DB` and `DC` directly.

Comment: what is the advantage of this over just defining `DB` and `DC` directly?

Comment: I was just going to update the answer to address that :) I suspect that usually there is no advantage.

Comment: I'm starting to see the wisdom of the golang designers of just not providing inheritance *at all*. I think, that while it is a good tool for certain specific use-cases, in "the wild" it just leads to too much nonsense. I do blame a lot of CS education, though, where inheritance is overemphasized.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What is the advantage of this? I only see the disadvantage of another line of code for each call. And regarding defining `DB` and `DC` directlly I would find myself write a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without knowing why you are creating subclasses of `B` or `C` (or `A`, for that matter). It's quite possible that inheritance isn't appropriate for whatever you are trying to do.